# Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember cmdlet not working

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, powershell-7.2

The following script, which should create a Service Principal in Azure and assign it a given Azure AD role, fails in the last step, precisely when assigning the role to the service principal.

```
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $tenantId

# Create the Azure AD Application Registration
$appRegistration = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName $spName

# Create the Service Principal
New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId $appRegistration.AppId

# Get the role object from the given role name
$AdminRoleObject = Get-AzureADDirectoryRole | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq $role}

# Assign the role to the app registration
Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId $AdminRoleObject.ObjectId -RefObjectId $appRegistration.ObjectId
```

The service principal is indeed created in Azure AD, but the script fails the Azure AD role assignment. By observing the error message, it seems that an extra `/` is added to the URL, like in the following: `https://graph.windows.net//`

The error is as follows:

```
Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember: Error occurred while executing AddDirectoryRoleMember  Code: Request_BadRequest Message: The URI 'https://graph.windows.net//xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx/directoryObjects/xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx' is not valid since it is not based on 'https://graph.windows.net/xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx/'. RequestId: ce7e548a-642a-4998-a153-910671c812ee DateTimeStamp: Tue, 18 Jan 2022 15:01:40 GMT HttpStatusCode: BadRequest HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request HttpResponseStatus: Completed
```

I am using `powershell 7.2`. Here's some more information about the environment:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.2.1
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.2.1
OS                             Darwin 21.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.2.0: Sun Nov 28 20:29:10 PST 2021; root:xnu-8019.61.5~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101
Platform                       Unix
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

Any idea if this is a bug, or if I'm doing something wrong? Or does someone does this task differently?

Comment: Please try by installing latest version of azure ad module . (install-module -name azuread).It looks like you are not assigning the role to  service principal but app registration, please recheck.

Comment: I tried to assign the role to the SP and also to the App Registration. Isn't it the same in the end? Both failed anyway! 

On MacOS I am unable to import AzureAD module after installing it... As I answered below, the only way I found to use Azure AD module, is by installing and importing AzureAD.Standard.Preview from the "Posh Test Gallery" repository. And it seems the Get-AzureADMSRoleDefinition cmdlet is not available in this module

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue related to the AzureAD module on PowerShell core as I was able to repro the same issue when I use extra `/`.
[image]

I was wondering if you tried the following alternative AzureAD cmdlet to assign directory role `New-AzureADMSRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionId {AdminRoleId} -PrincipalId {AppObjectID}  -DirectoryScopeId '/'` ? Because this cmdlet use https://graph.microsoft.com rather than https://graph.windows.net .

You could use `Get-AzureADMSRoleDefinition | select DisplayName, Id` to find out AdminRoleId.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadmsroleassignment?view=azureadps-2.0

Comment: I did think about using that cmdlet, but because I am using macOS, I am not able to import the standard AzureAD module, I get an error related with my machine architecture... The only way I found to use Azure AD module, is by installing and importing AzureAD.Standard.Preview from the "Posh Test Gallery" repository. And it seems the Get-AzureADMSRoleDefinition is not available in this module

Comment: The [AzureAD.Standard.Preview](https://www.poshtestgallery.com/packages/AzureAD.Standard.Preview/0.1.599.7) is private Preview release and last updated was on 8/30/2018 which is not recommended so best way in this scenario is to use Standard AzureAD module. If you're having trouble installing a specific package, try contacting the [owner of Azure AD package team](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureADPreview/2.0.1.18/ContactOwners). Meanwhile can try installing [Microsoft Graph module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.Graph/1.9.1) and lets know if that works.